# Can you use herein to refer back?

Tags: writing

As the title suggests, I would like to know if it is correct to use 'herein' to refer back. For instance, I have used the phrase 'in this paper' several times in a document and I wish to use another term to avoid repetition. Instead of saying 'In this paper we presented' I would like to say 'Herein we presented' is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can also just say "Here we presented...", rather than "herein".

Similarly "therein" can almost always be just "there".

Or, unless you are referring to another source due to you, "We presented" would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine as long as the reference is clear. Use the language to express your ideas as best you can. But if there is any doubt, make it explicit. A friendly reader might give you some advice on clarity.

You can also use "therein" for a more remote reference.

Comment: thank you so much. I wasn't sure. I've seen it used in the forward sense, for e.g., 'Herein we investigate' but not in the backward sense 'Herein we investigated'.

Comment: @Bob1986 If you need to distinguish between the two cases, Oxford Dictionaries Online offers "hereinbefore" and "hereinafter"; and I've seen "hereinaforesaid" in a piece of early-19th-century delegated legislation.  However, before going to such lengths to 'avoid repetition', take a look at [McIntyre (1997, _Interdiscip. Sci. Rev._ **22*:199-216)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/mem/papers/LHCE/lucidity-science-I.pdf).